# How to remove the "React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies" warning

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Here is my component function:

```
function RosterRows(props){
    const [rosterList,setRosterList]=useState({});
    const getData=async ()=>{
        let roster=new Roster();
        let rosterData=await roster.get(props.rosterYear,props.rosterMonth);
        setRosterList(rosterData);
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        getData();
        console.log(Object.keys(rosterList));
    },[]);
    
    return(
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    );
}
export default RosterRows
```

It prompts the following warning message when the component is called:

```
Line 14:7:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'getData' and 'rosterList'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

When I move the getData function into the useEffect function, it prompts:

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'props.rosterMonth', 'props.rosterYear', and 'rosterList'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

When I change function to the following:

```
import { useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import Roster from '../../../utils/roster';

function RosterRows(props){
    const [rosterList,setRosterList]=useState({});
    const rosterMonth=props.rosterMonth;
    const rosterYear=props.rosterYear;
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getData=async ()=>{
            let roster=new Roster();
            let rosterData=await roster.get(rosterYear,rosterMonth);
            setRosterList(rosterData);
        }
        getData();
        console.log(Object.keys(rosterList));
    },[]);
    
    return(
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    );
}
export default RosterRows
```

I got the following message:

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'rosterList', 'rosterMonth', and 'rosterYear'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

When the code is changed to the following:

```
function RosterRows(props){
    const [rosterList,setRosterList]=useState({});
    const rosterMonth=props.rosterMonth;
    const rosterYear=props.rosterYear;
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getData=async ()=>{
            let roster=new Roster();
            let rosterData=await roster.get(rosterYear,rosterMonth);
            setRosterList(rosterData);
            console.log(rosterData);
        }
        getData();
    
    },[]);
    
    return(
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    );
}
export default RosterRows
```

It prompts the following message:

```
Line 5:12:  'rosterList' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                    no-unused-vars

Line 17:7:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'rosterMonth' and 'rosterYear'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Would you tell me how to fix the problem?

Comment: The error could not be clearer what needs to be done. What part do you have problem with? The dependency array is the empty array at the end. You need to put things the error is telling you inside the array.

Comment: I am new to REACT component function, so I just want to know is there any way to remove the warning message.

Comment: The "console.log(Object.keys(rosterList));" run once and return the correct data.

Comment: `useEffect(() => { getData(); console.log(Object.keys(rosterList)); },[getData, rosterList]);`

Comment: it causes the infinite loop.

Comment: Instead of `console.log(rosterList)` move the `console.log` inside your `getData` and do `console.log(rosterData)` instead.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: You can use use callback , for get rid of infinity loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `console.log(rosterList)` inside the effect. `getData` sets the `rosterList` in the state but setting state is not synchronous in React.

This will work as expected and doesn't have infinite loop and properly specifies the effect's dependencies:

```
function RosterRows(props) {
  const [rosterList, setRosterList] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      let roster = new Roster();
      let rosterData = await roster.get(props.rosterYear, props.rosterMonth);
      console.log(Object.keys(rosterData));
      setRosterList(rosterData);
    };
    getData();
  }, [props.rosterYear, props.rosterMonth]);

  return (
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  );
}
export default RosterRows;
```

Comment: After several tried, I got a similar solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

If you ensure your useEffect hooks will just run once on component mount, you can just disable the eslint rule

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    const getData=async ()=>{
        let roster=new Roster();
        let rosterData=await roster.get(rosterYear,rosterMonth);
        setRosterList(rosterData);
    }
    getData();
    console.log(Object.keys(rosterList));
},[]); // eslint-disable-line
```

Comment: The eslint is there for a reason. This is a terrible advice.

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: Ahhh... so I said you should ensure your effect will execute only once, or you must put all the variables that the effect used into the second parameter of the hook